# Does Javascript simplify statements before execution?

Tags: javascript

I have recently been working on a small to medium sized game in JavaScript to familiarize myself with it and come from a background in C and Java. In my game I am using a few constant numbers to render all of my objects and I was wondering about the performance impact those would have. Both C and Java are languages with compilers that will automatically simplify simple statements such as 2 + 3 into 5 before the code is actually run. This is great because it means I can make my code more readable by having something like WINDOW_MAX_Y - SHIP_Y in my code and understand what it does later. Looking over my code recently however, I found a few lines of code that become very long when written in this style, and because JavaScript does not have a compiler I was wondering whether it would improve performance if I simplified everything into "magic numbers" or if JavaScript had some function that would automatically simplify the lines before execution like the C compiler. I would like to keep my code readable, however, if JavaScript does not simplify those statements I would love to know as they are run thousands of times per second.

Comment: You might read about how V8 tries to optimize code (while compiling): https://www.google.com/search?q=v8+compiler+optimizes

Comment: So V8 looks like an additional optional JavaScript compiler that I can implement myself to add performance gains to my project. I was wondering if that was the default behavior of JavaScript without any additions or if JavaScript had any type optimization between typing the code and running it.

Comment: @WiredOverload No, V8 is a Javascript runtime which is used by Chrome, as well as in some other environments like node.js. Its optimizations are performed automatically if your program is running in Chrome. Similar optimizations exist in the runtimes used by other browsers.

Comment: @duskwuff that's fantastic and means I don't need to redesign my code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily before execution but when the interpreter detects that the code is being used heavily.

You mention Java and this is good because I think you may be familiar with the concept since Java was one of the first languages to implement it. It's called just-in-time compilation (or JIT for short).

There is no standard that covers how JIT is to be implemented in Javascript. And there is no standard that mandates that a javascript interpreter must implement JIT (this is exactly the same for Java by the way, it is perfectly legal to implement a JVM that does not implement a JIT compiler). However, market forces have ensured that all current major javascript interpreters have implemented JIT (which may seem bit odd since all major javascript interpreters are free but they are competing for market share, not profit).

Similarly you mentioned C, which is nice because it also means you should be familiar with another concept. In C there is no standard defining how `a = 1 + 2` should be compiled to. There is a concept in the C standard that specifies the behaviour of such optimisations though: the **as-if** rule. It basically states that if a complier was to implement optimisations, the end result must be exactly the same as if there was no optimisation.

All major javascript interpreters currently have most of the common optimisations that compilers typically have. They are all slightly different (just as all C compilers are slightly different) but they all compile code just-in-time. In addition, most interpreters also perform optimisations during compilation to byte code.

Yes, there is byte code, just like Java. While there is no compilation step performed by the programmer, all current javascript interpreters compile to bytecode before execution just like Java. This is true for all modern "scripting" languages such as Python and Ruby.

My advice is basically if you don't worry about such things in C or Java then you should not need to worry about it in javascript. For things that you need to worry about in C (such as micro-optimisations) there is a subset of javascript called asm.js that is guaranteed to be compiled down to machine code instead of bytecode (if set up correctly).

Comment: That's a great write-up. I had heard of the Just In Time compiler, but had thought it was more for compatibility than for optimizations. Thanks.